# How does the Order By in c# actually works?

Tags: c#

I am working on a simple game in which I have to change the placements of characters in a string and in the internet I found this: it can be easily done by `OrderBy` but I'm not able to understand its implementation. This the code:

```
class Words
{
    public static int number = 0;
    public string[] word = { "herb", "cooler", "timeline" };

    public string Rearrange_word()
    {
        Random num = new Random();
        string rand = new string(this.word[number].OrderBy(s => (num.Next(2) % 2) == 0).ToArray());
        return rand;
    }
    public string current_word()
    {
        return word[number];
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code does not use the instance of `Random` anywhere, how can it return randomly sorted results?

Comment: @ZoharPeled i edit the code sir now check pls

Comment: ` Random num = new Random();`. You are not you using `num` in your code....

Comment: now check sir @ZoharPeled

Comment: If you want to find the right kind of sample code on the Internet then be sure to use the right Google query.  For this one it is "site:stackoverflow.com c# random shuffle".  The Q+A you now find has enough background info to learn how their solutions work.

Comment: @HansPassant sir can u help me with the order by line i cant seemed to find any thing specific

Comment: Order by returns a list that is ordered according to a criterion that you specify, in this case a random value. So the list should be randomized/shuffled.

Comment: yes i know sir and its working perfectly i am newbie and i have very little time i am just asking how is it working num is the random number how its working with num.Next(2)% can u explain a bit thank you really appriciate it @Hanskesting

Comment: [`Random.Next(Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_), [`%` Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator)

Comment: @ZoharPeled i read the page sir but didnt find anything on  that specific next(2) all of those are upper bounds and lower

Comment: `num.Next(2)` returns a random number that can either be 0 or 1, since it's upper bound is 2. The `%` operator is redundant in this comparison since it's result is the reminder of the number produced by `num.Next` divided by 2 - so it's either 0 or 1.

Comment: so how is ir Ordering the string for example the word is "Dog" and the random number generatted is 2 then how its going to work @ZoharPeled

Comment: the `OrderBy` method accepts a `Func<TSource, TKey>`, and sorts the `TSource` by the `TKey`. Since the result of the lambda is random, the order will also be random.

Comment: is thier any modification to this line u can suggest for simple understanding i mean i still not getting the use of 2%2 operation @ZoharPeled

Comment: As I said, the `% 2` is redundant in this case. BTW, so is the `==2`. In fact, you can simply do `OrderBy(s => num.Next())`. However, there are better ways to shuffle an array. search for the Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take these two lines of code:

```
   Random num = new Random(); // (1)
   string rand = new string( // (2)
       this.word[number]  // (3)
       .OrderBy(s => (num.Next(2) % 2) == 0) // (4)
       .ToArray()); // (5)
```

And disect them.

(1) Creates a new instance of the Random class, which generates (pseudo-)random numbers.
(2) Creates a new string from the character array that will be generated in the next lines.
(3) Get a specific word from your list. This is a `string` here, but treated as a sequence of `char`acters in the next line.
(4) Order this sequence of characters. For *each* of the characters in the string, get a *new* random value (in a way that is too complicated). Order the characters by this random value, in effect shuffling the characters.
(5) Create an array of characters out of this sequence, so that it can be used (see (2)) to create a new string

To explain step (4) a bit more: the `s => (num.Next(2) % 2) == 0` bit is called a "lambda expression". It is a condensed way to specify a function, in this case a function to transform each incoming value (here called `s` and having a datatype of `char`) to a value to order on.

That value-to-order-on completely ignores the character and starts by getting the next value from the random generator (`num.Next(2)`). The `2` means that the (`int`) value produced will be 0 or 1 (2 is the exclusive upper bound). The `% 2` takes the remainder after dividing by 2 - which in this case is just the value itself. Then that value is compaired against 0 (`== 0`), which effectively turns a `0` into `true` and a `1` into `false`. Again not useful (as others have remarked upon).

This part could have been rewritten as `.OrderBy(s => num.Next(2))` with the same results (apart from the fact that random numbers are used).